# Getting error as geckodriver.exe executable needs to be in PATH when running robot framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

Getting error as geckodriver.exe executable needs to be in PATH when running test runner file in robot framework

I have downloaded and added geckodriver path in executable path and system variable. But still facing the same.

As alternate way i tried same for chromedriver also, but still facing the same error

```
executable_path= "C:\New folder\geckodriver.exe"
```

[image]

I have followed whatever mentioned in,

[Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 1):

If that's the way you're setting the location of the binary (python?), there's a small but easily fixable mistake - the backslash (`\`) is an escape character in most programming languages, and when you want to use it literally - you have to escape itself - `\\`

```
executable_path= "C:\\New folder\\geckodriver.exe"
```

---

Apart from that, what can I say, the webdriver really needs to be in the PATH of the user if you don't want to specify ts location explicitly :)

Open Command Prompt (win+R, type "cmd") and run geckodriver.exe - if it returns no executable with that name is found, then you have to fix the PATH variable for the current user; or move the exe to a dir that's already there.
If it is found though - are you running your automation with the same OS user?

And to get the current value of your path, in cmd type `echo $PATH`; the webdriver binaries must be in one the directories there to be found.

Comment: I tried following things also.

1. different slash i tried( /, \ , \\)
2. win+R, type "cmd") and run geckodriver.exe : getting geckodriver INFO
3. are you running your automation with the same OS user? : Im running with local machine using my own credential. Not a VM.

Also i tried to set C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe and executed, getting error like, chromedriver needs to be in path.

Comment: geckodriver is not the same as chromedriver ..

Comment: How to identify which from which location it takes the gecckodriver? i.e when we give GECKODRIVER in cmd window, it read from which location, how we can know?

Comment: I've ammended the answer to show how you can see your current path; `where geckodriver.exe` to answer your immediate question - will print you where is that file that _is_ found.